# iOS Calendar-like shared element screen transitions

Tags: react-native, animation, shared-element-transition, react-animated

Not sure if this is the right place for this but I'm wondering how I can create screen transitions like this. Specifically, how do I make it so the week in focus animates into position? If it's too difficult to explain, would it be possible to point me in the right direction?

I have looked into using shared element transitions but can't quite get it to work properly. Is it possible to do this with a single react-navigation screen transition or would I need to animate individual components? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]